# Substitution with trigs (not integrals)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am currently trying to find out the values of $x$ and $\theta$, given the two following statements. I have tried using substitution, but I am not quite getting it. I would be extremely glad if I could see how one reaches the answers of $x$ and $\theta$!

$8  -(x\cos(\theta))+(5(\sin45)) = 0$

$12 -(x\sin(\theta))-(5(cos45)) = 0$

Comment: are the angles in degrees?

Comment: Oh, yes. The angles are in degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

I would say

$x\sin \theta =12 -5\cos 45,\,\,x\cos \theta =8+5\sin 45$

$\tan \theta=\frac{12 -5(cos45))}{8+5(\sin45)}=\frac{12 -5\sqrt{2}/2}{8+5\sqrt{2}/2}\Rightarrow \theta,\,\sin \theta,\cos \theta,\,\Rightarrow x$

Comment: This trick of solving for $x\sin\theta$ and $y\sin\theta$, then dividing the equations is ***super*** useful, especially in elementary/first-year physics.  (These sorts of equations come up a lot, especially in problems dealing with a box on an inclined plane. `;)`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that explanation, just worked it out and finally understood how to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use $\sin 45 = \cos 45 = 1/\sqrt 2$

Then you have:

$$8+\frac{5}{\sqrt2}-x\cos\theta=0$$
and
$$12+\frac{5}{\sqrt2}-x\sin\theta=0$$

Knowing that $\cos^2\theta +\sin^2\theta=1$ and with

$$\frac{128+25}{2}=x^2\sin^2\theta$$
$$\frac{188+25}{2}=x^2\cos^2\theta$$

you get:
$$x^2=x^2\sin^2\theta+x^2\cos^2\theta=233$$
Inserting this in the first equation you might get:
$$\theta=\arccos\left(\frac{\sqrt212+5}{\sqrt{466}}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

we have
$8+\frac{5}{2}\sqrt{2}=x\cos(\theta)$ (1)
$12-\frac{5}{2}\sqrt{2}=x\sin(\theta)$ (2)
squaring and adding both equations we get
$\left(8+\frac{5}{2}\sqrt{2}\right)^2+\left(12-\frac{5}{2}\sqrt{2}\right)^2=x^2$